# Jquery - Live Fancbox trigger

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Wondered if someone out there fancies saving my sanity!?

I'm trying to trigger a dynamically loaded form to open into Fancybox on click.  It works - but only after two clicks...!?  First click does nothing - 2nd works, then it will work fine with just one click..  same in every browser.

This is a preview of code in current state.. http://fb.mobilechilli.com/chilli_shop/index-shop_xml.php

```
 $('.overlayLink').live('click', function() {

                    $("a#inline").fancybox({'hideOnContentClick': true});
                    $(".hidden_link").fancybox().trigger('click');
                    var formName = $(this).attr("name");
                    setTimeout(function() {document.getElementById(formName).submit();}, 500);

});
```

Any help very gratefully received as they need it live in an hour and i'm pulling my hair out!!!

Cheers
Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me that you are applying fancy box on the first click and then every click after that works.

You need to apply it before the click, so outside of the `live` event.

Also `a#inline` should probably be changed to use a class `a.inline` instead as you have multiple elements with that ID which is invalid html.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just load the data directly in the fancybox?

```
$.fancybox(CONTENT, {
  options
});
```

Comment: Hi,cheers for that - my main issue is that it takes 2 clicks to trigger fancybox.  the form part of the equation works fine, even if I remove the form it still takes two clicks to trigger fancybox!